# I can't disable rendering a text in a div container by using disable-twb

Tags: php, zend-framework2, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using TwbBundle with Zend framework 2 and trying to create username textbox with bootstrap glyphicon-user.

This is a part from the form code:

```
$this->add(array(
            'disable-twb' => true,
            'name' => 'usr_name',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'class'  => 'form-control',
                'placeholder' => 'username',
            ),

        ));
```

And here is a part from the view phtml:

```
    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px; " class="input-group">

        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
        </span>
        <?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('usr_name')); ?>

   </div>
```

But `'disable-twb' => true` doesn't remove the div wrapper from the username element.
And the rendering is a mess.
Am I doing something wrong here ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `formRow` helper, as far as I can tell, the disable option isn't available for that helper.

I'm not that familiar with the bundle in question, but a quick scan of the readme would suggest the `FormElement` helper is a better fit for your task and seems to support pre/appended add-ons

https://github.com/neilime/zf2-twb-bundle#form-element--twbbundleformviewhelpertwbbundleformelement

Comment: What kind of bundle they use in general for bootstrap 3 for Zend framework 2?

Answer (score 0):

The *disable-twb* option must be set into an *options* array :

```
$this->add(array(

    'name' => 'usr_name',
    'attributes' => array(
        'type'  => 'text',
        'class'  => 'form-control',
        'placeholder' => 'username',
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'disable-twb' => true,
    )

));
```